# Cookie customization popup doesn't appear on per-site Metas

Tags: support, bug, per-site-meta, popups, cookies

I went to [Meta AU](https://meta.askubuntu.com) (with a cleared cache and cookies) in search of a question, but the new cookie customization notice didn't come out.  It appears when you visit the [main site](https://askubuntu.com), but not on per-site Metas, it seems.  Is this the intended behavior?

Comment: This is even if you haven't interacted with the notice on main?

Comment: @BSMP Yes, even if I don't touch the main popup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

This has been fixed.  Here's a screenshot of the popup from Meta Stack Overflow:

[image]